# How can I rename field in search_fields of django rest_framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I have

```
class ProductSearch(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ProductSearchSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    filter_fields = ['meta_data', 'store__district__id']
```

but when I make  search through api I need to enter

`"store__district__id": "blabla"`

but instead of this I just want

`"district_id": "x"`

anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

Customize a search filter like this:

```py
from rest_framework import filters

class ProductSearchFilter(filters.SearchFilter):
    def get_search_fields(self, view, request):
        fields = super(CustomSearchFilter, self).get_search_fields(view, request)
        if 'district_id' in fields:
            fields['store__district__id'] = fields.pop('district_id')
        return fields
```

and place it in your `filter_backends` and put `district_id` in `search_fields` of the view:

```py
class ProductSearch(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ProductSearchSerializer
    filter_backends = [ProductSearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['meta_data', 'district_id']
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!